# Proving the existence of $P$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}[X]$ , such that : $\int_{0}^{1}fP = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need help with this problem.

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$, suppose that there exists two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)f(b)<0$. Prove that there exist $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$, a strictly positive polynomial on $[0,1]$, such that: $\int_{0}^{1}fP = 0$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a nice question, so where did you   find it? From whichever textbook etc. you found it, you might have been given hints on how to solve it e.g. if it part of the problems section of some chapter, which one?

Comment: ENS entrance exams, I have tried proof by contradiction but to no avail

Comment: I would try the intermediate value theorem, that is, propose a continuous (=parameter dependent) family of positive polynomials such that there are polynomials in this family where the integral is positive and where the integral is negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to find two positive polynomials $P_1,P_2$ such that $\int_0^1 fP_1 < 0 < \int_0^1 fP_2$, and we will see why.

While I seek out an easier route, let me mention this one : given $g \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$, the Bernstein construction shows that there exist non-negative polynomials $P_n$ such that $P_n \to g$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ (because $g$ values are used in the construction and these are non-negative). But given any non-negative polynomial $P$, simply consider the polynomial $P + \frac 1n$, this is a family of positive polynomials uniformly coming down to $P$. In conclusion, given $g \geq 0$ there exists a family of positive polynomials converging uniformly to $g$ (diagonal sequence).

Now, suppose that $\int fP > 0$ for all positive polynomials $P$. Then, by density and uniform convergence implying integral convergence, $\int fg \geq 0$ for all positive continuous functions $g$. This contradicts $f(a) < 0$, since one can take $g$ to be zero except in a a neighbourhood of $a$ in which $f$ is negative, and hence get a contradiction.

Thus, for some positive polynomial $P_1$ we have $\int fP_1 < 0$. Using $b$ in a similar way gives the existence of a positive polynomial $P_2$ such that $\int fP_2 > 0$.

Finally, consider the family of polynomials $Q_t = tP_1 + (1-t)P_2$, $t \in [0,1]$. This is a family of *positive* polynomials (because for every $t$ we have $Q_t \geq \min\{P_1,P_2\} > 0$), and note that $\int fQ_0 < 0$ and $\int fQ_1 > 0$. The proof is finished once we observe that $t \to \int fQ_t$ is a continuous function (uniform convergence and all that) and use IVT.

As to the explicit construction of $P_1,P_2$ : I'd like to see it, I thought about it for some time and couldn't come up with something at all.